# Derivative of $\arctan y $

Tags: calculus

I'm given $f(x)=\tan x$ and $g(y)=\arctan y.$
 I am also told that $g'(y)=\frac{1}{f'(g(y))}.$

I'm then asked to use this to find the derivative of $\arctan x.$

Here is what I have so far:

$$g'(y)=\frac{1}{\sec^2(g(y))}=\frac{1}{\tan^2(g(y))+1}$$

I'm not sure what to do next though.

Comment: Please don't delete your question as soon as someone answers. This is not fair to the person who has answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

The next step is to use
$$
\tan(g(y))=\tan(\arctan(y))=y
$$ giving
$$
g'(y)=\frac{1}{\sec^2(g(y))}=\frac{1}{\tan^2(g(y))+1}=\frac1{1+y^2}
$$ as wanted.